# Download multiple files with Sails.js 0.12

Tags: javascript, download, sails.js

I try to download an uploaded file from a data folder, OUT of the asset folder in a Sails.js 0.12 app.

I ended up installing Skipper-disk npm to do so with :

```
var SkipperDisk = require('skipper-disk');
var fileAdapter = SkipperDisk(/* optional opts */);

res.attachment('./data/'+req.param('product_id')+ '/' + req.param('file'));
fileAdapter.read('./data/'+req.param('product_id')+ '/' + req.param('file'))
.on('error', function (err){
    return res.serverError(err);
})
.pipe(res);
```

I'm a bit disappointed about it because I wanted to find a way to do it without installing more dependencies (skipper-disk). I tried things like : [sailsjs send a file on the fly with res.attachment()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500426/sailsjs-send-a-file-on-the-fly-with-res-attachment), [How do I authenticate access to assets folder in sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24235653/how-do-i-authenticate-access-to-assets-folder-in-sails-js/24247649#24247649), [Uploading multiple files with Sails.js 0.10 and Skipper using Dropzone.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905839/uploading-multiple-files-with-sails-js-0-10-and-skipper-using-dropzone-js), [Sails.js Download File To Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50142797/sails-js-download-file-to-client), and many more, but nothing else work.

Is there another way than skipper-disk to make the upload work ?

Also, I needed more than one file downloaded with the previous controller action, but my request from the front end only opens the first file selected.

Here's that code :

```
files.forEach(function(file) {
    window.open('/product/' + id + '/download/' + file, '_blank');
});
```

Is there a way to get multiple files from the back end ?

Comment: Have you try out the skipper itself beside skipper-disk?

I guess the default folder is: .tmp/uploads/ and ensure that your path is at the correct location path.

Also try this: http://blog.tunaxor.me/2017/01/07/upload-download-sails/

Comment: To upload files I use : `uploadFile.upload({ 
            dirname: '../../data/'+req.session.selectedProduct.id,
            saveAs: req.file('file')._files[0].stream.filename
        }, function onUploadComplete(err, files) { ... }` and it works, and I think it is skipper ?

Answer (score 0):

Well for my first question, I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it, but this works fine without Skipper-disk (the server on which the app is running is a pain when I need to install a new npm, so I try to do without !) :

```
const Path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.createReadStream(Path.resolve('./data/'+req.param('product_id')+ '/' + req.param('file')))
.on('error', function (err) {
    return res.serverError(err);
})
.pipe(res);
```